# How to differentiate between 2 routes one of which is "/:param" and other is "/param"

Tags: express, url-routing, routeparams

I am a novice in expressjs and don't know much about routing  and such concepts in expressjs. While reading about it, I saw that one can set a route like

```
route1 = app.get("/:param",callback)
```

where param will become the route param variable and all such get requests like: "/foo" or "/bar" will correspond to that route.

My question is: can I have a route now that is

```
route2 = app.get("/param", callback)
```

or

```
app.get("/anyOtherRoute",callback)
```

If so, how can I know that the request is for route1 and not for route2 (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't, really.  But you can define your routes in an order such that you have different behaviour for `anyOtherRoute`.

For example:

`app.get('/anyOtherRoute', doFoo);
app.get('/:param', doBar);`

If `doFoo` terminates the request without calling `next()` you'll get the separation I think you're looking for.

`doFoo` would be called first since `express` goes through the routes in the order that they are defined and added to the app.

Comment: More specifically, express routes are evaluated top down, I would update your answer to specify that instead of "define your routes in a such an order" since that is a bit vague.